# What should we do when there is absolutely nil responses/comments to a question with answers?

Tags: discussion

A few days back, I answered a CSS [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25104850/flipping-card-css-issue). Another user had answered the same question too. But till date there has been no response (or) not even a comment from the original poster of the question indicating whether it really helped or not. While I know that these cases are bound to happen, the thing that I find strange with this case is that the question has been favorited by some users and even has upvote but there has been absolutely no response (positive/negative) on the answers (except one which I received today).

I even left a couple of comments under the question for the OP to take notice of the answer. But after reading through a few meta posts today I realized that it is not acceptable to ping users reminding them of an answer (as SO already does notify users).

Please note that I am not trying to blame the OP of the question or requesting for votes on the answer. My concern is on whether that answer is really helpful to future readers (or) should I remove it. I am seeking guidance on what should be my course of action in this case? I don't want to leave an invaluable/incorrect answer lying around.

I have been actively involved with StackOverflow for over a year now and in most cases (99% or even more) I have found that any user who asks a question will atleast indicate whether the answer helped them or not. So, this case that I am highlighting here in this question is probably a rare scenario. But the lack of response (not only to my answer but the question in general) has left me puzzled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you've answered to the best of your ability based on the information given and asked any clarifying questions in the comments already, there's not a lot else you can do. Vote to close if more information is *required* to answer.

The user has activity since the question was posted, just not on that question. We can't force them to respond. Since you've done all you can, just move on and answer other questions. Star the question if you want to be notified of any future updates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. I didn't close vote because I thought the question was clear enough. As I said, my concern was not even with the OPs acceptance (or lack of it) but more on the quality of the answer and whether it was of good enough to help future readers. But yeah as you said, I think there is nothing we can do about it.