# Feature request: "Post notice" suggesting to accept an answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, new-users, post-notice

In line with the abandoned [rule proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418169/1426891), I suggest the implementation of a ["Post Notice"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/201031) question banner in the style of the "Close Vote" banner, *visible only to question authors, answerers, and moderators*, instructing users about their *prerogative* to accept an answer.

The text would look *something* like this, made to dovetail with the ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) help page, but I'm not married to this specific text at all:

> Your question has an answer! Once you consider your problem to be solved, you can [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark next to it. You can also vote on the answer once you earn the [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) privilege.

I've mocked it up here:

[image: Mock post notice]

#### Motivation

1. Question askers don't know what to do after they receive a helpful answer, as noted by the "thanks!" or "+1" comments and lack of answer acceptance. Those unnecessary comments need moderation.
2. Question answerers can't see or don't trust the other nudges (which seem to just be [tooltips and tour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418169/rule-proposal-comments-asking-for-accepts-and-votes-shall-no-longer-be-allowed#:%7E:text=didn%27t%20really%20exist.-,Both%20the%20tour%20and%20tooltips%20cover%20this,-Accepted%20answers%20are) right now). As far as anyone can tell, nothing *on the question page* gives the user any instruction how to respond to the answer. The reputation system and post-answer options work differently on the Stack Exchange network than on other services like Reddit, so it's reasonable to guess that a new asker wouldn't know what to do.
3. The impulse to teach new users how the site works can result in "accept an answer" suggestions that seem self-serving or condescending, especially when posted by an answerer in their own question comments. Even the most appropriate of those comments eventually need moderation too.
4. The suggestion to accept doesn't really benefit anyone other than the question asker, so nobody else needs to read it. For other readers, it's just noise.

#### Advantages

1. Authority: The suggestion comes from the system, not one given user.
2. Auto-Moderation: The suggestion is not a comment in the comment system, and it disappears automatically if the answerer takes action. The message could even be hidden automatically after a certain time period.
3. Appropriateness: The suggestion can be shown only to users who have *never* accepted an answer, and only on non-closed non-duplicate questions.
4. Approved text: The text can be carefully reviewed and approved, and updated all at once if it needs revision. Comments can't be updated like that.
5. Answerer visibility: Because the answerers can see the post notice too, they can verify that the user has already been suggested to accept, and will be less inclined to provide that help themselves. This reduces the moderation comment count and post noise, as the May 2022 [rule proposal/announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418169/1426891) was intended to do.

#### Potential problems

1. Proliferation: This is another post notice, like a lock message or close message. If these proliferate, it can push the content much further down the page.
2. Private notice: Other users and answerers can't see the notice, so there's no way to tell whether the user was nudged or not.
3. Prejudice: Answerers can tell whether the user is eligible or not. They might put less effort into curating their answers for users who were nudged (less "ROI" for folks who care about rep), or might be more tempted to post a comment if they see that the system does *not* nudge the user.
4. Prioritization: This would require SE code changes, so it may fall down the priority list. Moderation rules can be changed immediately without changing SE engineer priorities.

#### Related

- May 2022: [Rule proposal: comments asking for accepts and votes shall no longer be allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418169/1426891)
- October 2019: [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/201031)
- December 2015: [Encourage users to accept answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313206/1426891)
- August 2014: [What should we do when there is absolutely nil responses/comments to a question with answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268009/1426891)
- April 2014: [Dealing with an answer that wasn't accepted (maybe because a user is a newbie on Stack Overflow)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251288/1426891)

Comment: How long would this display for? Would it be time based or event based? I don't necessarily like the idea of needing to accept an answer to clear this banner. Not all questions need to have an accepted answer. Accepting an answer can also _cause_ confusion in cases where there are several different approaches that all work (as an example).

Comment: I would also add to this banner a mention about posting "thanks" as a comment. Tell them not to do both.

Comment: @Dharman Adding "don't post thanks" is absolutely in scope; I omitted it in my example for brevity but I'm very open to add it.

Comment: @HenryEcker As in Advantage #2, dismissal could be both time-based and event-based: either you accept on *any* of your questions or it ages out. The trick with a time-based dismissal is that some askers might only return to SO after a month or three, and those are also folks who we'd want to see a banner. Ultimately if the banner doesn't go away automatically I don't see it as a big downside: nobody else sees it, it's not as intrusive as a ping/notification/email, and a well-phrased nudge says that the asker *may* accept the answer without suggesting it is required.

Comment: If we give the asker a button to manually dismiss the notice (could be simply a simple `X` or something more explicit like "I'm not satisfied with the answer(s)"), there will be no need for a time-based dismissal. Then, whether or not the system should re-show the notice if the question gets another answer may be discussed. On one hand, it's a reminder because the OP technically still never accepted an answer before, but on the other hand, it might come off as a little pushy.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine I did think about that, but then we're adding database state to either the post or the account, which would surely increase the implementation cost. Also, if this notice stays answerer-visible, then the answerer would potentially get to see whether the asker dismissed the box, which seems privacy-violating. I figure that if we don't give a dismiss box for the closure notifications even for answers that will never be reopened, then we can omit a dismiss box for askers who have not and will not accept the present answers.

Comment: FWIW, there's already a reminder for this, [on the user's Activity page, with complex criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378929/241919). I did think about whether to adjust the criteria/message.

Comment: I noticed that the mock proposal has "users who have contributed an answer". If this were to be implemented, would you prefer to have a personalized message just like post notice for close reasons? Like, "*The system is already showing the relevant help center ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to the asker. Please refrain from posting any comments suggesting the asker to accept or upvote any answer.*"

Comment: @AndrewT. I wouldn't have suggested that myself—it feels a little more firm about the recommendation than I think the community wants right now—but I am open to it if it's easy to implement. It's consistent with current moderator *requests*, and in the interest of compromise I can see how clearer guidance to answerers would make this a more appealing change to prioritize.